# Unable to let UIImageView be sender in prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiimageview, segue

I am trying to pass an image from one view to another, however when i run the below code, it keeps entering where it says "ENTERING HERE". How do i fix this?

```
@IBOutlet weak var feedImage: UIImageView!

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! questionCell

//other code here ...

    myCell.feedImage.tag = indexPath.row
    print(myCell.feedImage.tag)

    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:Selector("imageTapped:"))
    myCell.feedImage.userInteractionEnabled = true
    myCell.feedImage.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
}

func imageTapped(img: AnyObject)
{

    performSegueWithIdentifier("questionToFullScreen", sender: self)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "questionToFullScreen" {
        guard let feedImage = sender as? UIImageView else { 
        //ENTERING HERE
        return }
        guard let destinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? fullScreenImageViewController else { return }

      //send the image to the next view
      destinationViewController.image = resultsArray[feedImage.tag].imageFile
     }
}
```

Comment: First check you are getting image or not and the add writedestinationViewController.image = resultsArray[feedImage.tag].imageFile as UIIMage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change "img: AnyObject" --> "tap: UITapGestureRecognizer"
2. Change "sender: self" --> "sender: tap.view"

   ```
   func imageTapped(tap: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

       performSegueWithIdentifier("questionToFullScreen", sender: tap.view)
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This might be the problem:

Instead of this :

```
func imageTapped(img: AnyObject)
{

    performSegueWithIdentifier("questionToFullScreen", sender: self)
}
```

write this:

```
func imageTapped(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer)
    {

        performSegueWithIdentifier("questionToFullScreen", sender: self)
    }
```

Comment: unfortunately that didnt solve it, im still entering the else statement and returning

Comment: are you sure you are getting feedImage? It seems your feed image is nil thats why its entering in guard's else statement

Comment: I dont think i am getting feedImage, i agree that is the problem. Im not passing it into the prepareForSegue function correctly

Comment: unless and until you get image that piece of code is not gonna work. and do remember that your imageView is not a sender, tapGesture is. U need to extract image from tapgesture

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending an `UIImage` as a **sender**. You are sending `tapGestureRecognizer`.

```
func imageTapped(img: AnyObject)
{
    performSegueWithIdentifier("questionToFullScreen", sender: self)
}
```

sender is a UITapGestureRecognizer now. You can't send UIImage with sender argument.

`self` means who is the triggered your action. In your case it is `tapGestureRecognizer.`

Comment: But is that not why i add "guard let feedImage = sender as? UIImageView else { return }"?
In any case, how do i solve it?